# interviewstreet Triplet challenge

Tags: algorithm

There is an integer array d which does not contain more than two elements of the same value. How many distinct ascending triples (d[i] < d[j] < d[k], i < j < k) are present?

**Input format:**

The first line contains an integer N denoting the number of elements in the array. This is followed by a single line containing N integers separated by a single space with no leading/trailing spaces

**Output format:**

A single integer that denotes the number of distinct ascending triples present in the array

**Constraints:**

N <= 10^5
Every value in the array is present at most twice
Every value in the array is a 32-bit positive integer

**Sample input:**

```
6 
1 1 2 2 3 4
```

**Sample output:**

```
4
```

**Explanation:**

The distinct triplets are

```
(1,2,3)
(1,2,4)
(1,3,4)
(2,3,4)
```

Another test case:

**Input:**

```
10
1 1 5 4 3 6 6 5 9 10
```

**Output:**

```
28
```

I tried to solve using DP. But out of 15 test cases only 7 test cases passed.
Please help solve this problem.

Comment: What are other sample inputs and answers?

Comment: In your sample input, numbers are sorted. Is input sorted or unsorted?

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky: If the question doesn't say anything, it is normal to assume the worst case (unsorted).

Comment: And one more thing.  It is not clear from the question if triples are triples values or indexes of values?

Comment: If you passed 7/15, check the type of the accumulator. The result can overflow 32-bit integer. You need 64-bit integer for this.

Comment: In the final example (1 1 5 4 3 6 6 5 9 10), I count 30 solutions.

Answer (score 8):

You should note that you only need to know the number of elements that are smaller/larger than  a particular element to know how many triples it serves as the middle point for. Using this you can calculate the number of triples quite easily, the only remaining problem is to get rid of duplicates, but given that you are limited to at most 2 of the same element, this is trivial.

I solved using a Binary Index Tree http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees.

I also did a small write up, http://www.kesannmcclean.com/?p=223.

Comment: I think you should put the content of your blog here. I don't get how you hash the elements, but it must be able to preserve the order of the elements, or am I missing something?

Comment: @nhahtdh 

You don't need to care about the order of the elements, that's the main idea behind solving the problem. You count the triplets based on the item in the middle position, which makes it a lot simpler since you only worry about the number of elements which are smaller, and the number of elements which are larger than every particular element.

The hash is used as the back-end store of the Binary Indexed Tree rather than an array since the elements are sparse in the rang 0-2^32.

Comment: I know the idea. I thought of the roughly the same algorithm (BIT, 2 scans), except for the hashing part - which I'm asking you about. My approach: I sort the numbers by value to use index for the BIT.

Comment: @nhahtdh The hashing doesn't have anything to do with it other than to be used as the store for the Binary Indexed Tree. There is nothing important about it. I just replaced the usual array with the hash, because trying to allocate an array of size 2^32 will fail in java for two reasons: Arrays are indexed by integers, and are limited to 2^32-1 indexes, and it takes too much heap space... Sorry if I'm not answering your question correctly, but there is really nothing special about the hash. All the logic is in the code for the BIT.

Comment: I did these kinds of problem so I already know about the space and time problems. But thanks for the hashing idea.

Comment: @nhahtdh Also you can't sort the numbers, this will result in incorrect answers.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I did wrote an answer for this question, it was off the target so I deleted it (I search for the number of triples of **indices** that has the properties, rather than number of unique triples of **values**), but it can be slightly modified to answer this question. (Sorting is done to reverse the role of **index** and **value**).

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.jai;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Triplets {

    int[] lSmaller, rLarger, treeArray, dscArray, lFlags, rFlags;

    int size, count = 0;

    Triplets(int aSize, int[] inputArray) {
        size = aSize;
        lSmaller = new int[size];
        rLarger = new int[size];
        dscArray = new int[size];
        int[] tmpArray = Arrays.copyOf(inputArray, inputArray.length);
        Arrays.sort(tmpArray);
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> tmpMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (!tmpMap.containsKey(tmpArray[i])) {
                count++;
                tmpMap.put(tmpArray[i], count);
            }
        }
        count++;
        treeArray = new int[count];
        lFlags = new int[count];
        rFlags = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            dscArray[i] = tmpMap.get(inputArray[i]);
        }

    }

    void update(int idx) {
        while (idx < count) {
            treeArray[idx]++;

            idx += (idx & -idx);
        }
    }

    int read(int index) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (index > 0) {
            sum += treeArray[index];
            index -= (index & -index);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    void countLeftSmaller() {
        Arrays.fill(treeArray, 0);
        Arrays.fill(lSmaller, 0);
        Arrays.fill(lFlags, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int val = dscArray[i];
            lSmaller[i] = read(val - 1);
            if (lFlags[val] == 0) {
                update(val);
                lFlags[val] = i + 1;
            } else {
                lSmaller[i] -= lSmaller[lFlags[val] - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    void countRightLarger() {

        Arrays.fill(treeArray, 0);
        Arrays.fill(rLarger, 0);
        Arrays.fill(rFlags, 0);
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int val = dscArray[i];
            rLarger[i] = read(count - 1) - read(val);
            if (rFlags[val] == 0) {
                update(val);
                rFlags[val] = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    long countTriplets() {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sum += lSmaller[i] * rLarger[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[] a = new int[N];
        String[] strs = br.readLine().split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
        Triplets sol = new Triplets(N, a);
        sol.countLeftSmaller();
        sol.countRightLarger();
        System.out.println(sol.countTriplets());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For tentative algorithm that I came up with, it should be:

<s>`(K-1)!^2`</s>

where K is number of unique elements.

**EDIT**

After more thinking about this:

```
      SUM[i=1,K-2]  SUM[j=i+1,K-1]    SUM[m=j+1,K]   1
 =>   SUM[i=1,K-2]  (SUM[j=i+1,K-1]   (K-j))
```

Comment: No - it is not, if triples are values from the list (not indexes).  OP should clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

- if the input is not sorted (the question is not clear about this): sort it
- remove the duplicated items (this step could be conbined with the first step)
- now pick 3 items. Since the items are already sorted, the three chosen items are ordered as well
- IIRC there are (n!) / ((n-3)! * 3!) ways to pick the three items; with n := the number of unique items

Comment: This algorithm is incorrect. E.g. 3, 2, 1 should yield 0 rather than 1

Comment: At the time I wrote this, the question was not very clear, at least not to me. The Algorithm *may* be correct for other intrepretations of the question.

Comment: No, for competitive programming/online judge question, if the question doesn't say something, worst case must be assumed. (I have looked at the test data, and it contains cases where the numbers are unsorted).

Comment: I have *not* looked at the test data, only looked here. With implies that the question as posed here is incomplete.

Comment: I admit the question is incomplete in SO format, but it is complete for a competitive programming problem (the programmer should assume nothing outside the problem statement). Anyway, I added another test case that comes with the problem to clarify the question in SO format.

Comment: Is changing the rules during the game also part of competitive programming?

Comment: (Note that I'm not the OP) No, usually not. But competitive programming question trains one to think of all cases, where the problem statement does not explicitly say about. Problem 100 on UVa (The 3n + 1 problem) contains such trap.

Answer (score 0):

@hadron: exactly, I couldn get my head around on why it should be **28** and not **35** for a set of 7 distinct numbers *

*[Since the ques is about ascending triplets, repeated numbers can be discarded].*

btw, here's a very bad Java solution(N^3):

I have also printed out the possible triplets:

I'm also thinking about some function that dictates the no: of triplets possible for input 'N'

- 4  **4**
- 5  **10**
- 6  **20**
- 7  **35**
- 8  **56**
- 9  **84**

  package org.HackerRank.AlgoChallenges;

  import java.util.Iterator;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.util.TreeSet;

  public class Triplets {

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      int result = 0;
      int n = scanner.nextInt();
      Object[] array = new Object[n];
      TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
      /*
       * for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { array[i] = scanner.nextInt(); }
       */

      while (n>0) {
          treeSet.add(scanner.nextInt());
          n--;
      }
      scanner.close();

      Iterator<Integer> iterator = treeSet.iterator();
      int i =0;
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          //System.out.println("TreeSet["+i+"] : "+iterator.next());
          array[i] = iterator.next();
          //System.out.println("Array["+i+"] : "+array[i]);
          i++;
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < (array.length-2); j++) {
          for (int j2 = (j+1); j2 < array.length-1; j2++) {
              for (int k = (j2+1); k < array.length; k++) {
                  if(array[j]!=null && array[j2]!=null && array[k]!=null){
                      System.out.println("{ "+array[j]+", "+array[j2]+", "+array[k]+" }");
                      result++;
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      System.out.println(result);
  }
  ```

Comment: Even I believe that It should be 35.

Answer (score 0):

One of solution in  python:

```
from itertools import combinations as comb
def triplet(lis):
    done = dict()
    result = set()
    for ind, num in enumerate(lis):
        if num not in done:
            index = ind+1
            for elm in comb(lis[index:], 2):
                s,t = elm[0], elm[1]
                if (num < s < t):
                    done.setdefault(num, None)
                    fin = (num,s,t)
                    if fin not in result:
                        result.add(fin)
    return len(result)

test = int(raw_input())
lis = [int(_) for _ in raw_input().split()]
print triplet(lis)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you care about complexity?

Is the input array sorted?

if you don't mind about complexity you can solve it in complexity of N^3.

The solution with complexity N^3:
If it not sorted, then sorted the array.
Use 3 for loops one inside the other and go threw the array 3 times for each number.
Use hash map to count all the triples. The key will be the triple it self and the value will be the number of occurences.

It should be something like this:

```
for (i1=0; i1<N; i1++) {
    for (i2=i1; i2<N; i2++) {
        for (i3=i2; i3<N; i3++) {
            if (N[i1] < N[i2] < N[i3]) {
                /* if the triple exists in the hash then 
                        add 1 to its value
                    else 
                        put new triple to the hash with 
                        value 1 
                */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result = number of triples in the hash;

I didn't try it but I think it should work.

Comment: -1 N^2 is already too slow. N^3 will takes even longer to complete with N can go up to 10^5.