# Interviewstreet Triplet

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [interviewstreet Triplet challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928575/interviewstreet-triplet-challenge)

There is an integer array `d` which does not contain more than two elements of the same value. How many distinct ascending triples `(d[i] < d[j] < d[k], i < j < k)` are present?

**Input format:**

The first line contains an integer `N` denoting the number of elements in the array. This is followed by a single line containing `N` integers separated by a single space with no leading/trailing spaces

**Output format:**

A single integer that denotes the number of distinct ascending triples present in the array

**Constraints:**

```
N <= 10^5
```

Every element of the array is present at most twice

Every element of the array is a 32-bit positive integer

**Sample input:**

```
6

1 1 2 2 3 4
```

**Sample output:**

```
4
```

**Explanation:**

The distinct triplets are

```
(1,2,3)
(1,2,4)
(1,3,4)
(2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I assumed that the integers were ordered, which wasn't mentioned in your answer. With unordered integers, no optimization is possible, you'd have to use the brute force counting approach. If they are sorted, continue reading.

---

Thing is, you don't really need a lot of programming here. This is more of a mathematical problem.

First, it doesn't matter if there are 1, 2 or more occurences of an integer. The resulting triplets ave to be unique anyway. This reduces to merely counting how many different integers there are in the array. Name that variable `s`.

Then we merely apply following formula:

```
result = 0;
for(first_index = 0; first_index < s; first_index++) {
    for(second_index = first_index + 1; second_index < s; second_index++) {
        result += s - second_index - 1;
    }
}
return result;
```

This can, however, be simplified. Now, if we reason about the values `s - second_index - 1` takes for one outer loop, that's just the row of all integers from 0 to `s - 2` reversed! Aren't we glad that there's a formula for its sum: where `n` is an integer, `n * (n + 1) / 2` is the sum of the first `n` integers.

This means we can optimize our program to:

```
result = 0;
for(first_index = 0; first_index < s; first_index++) {
    result += (s - 2 - first_index) * (s - 2 - first_index + 1) / 2;
}
```

Note that we can further simplify this to `result = (x^3 - 3*x^2 + 2*x) / 6`.

Comment: Not sure how your formula works... the only input to your formula is the number of unique elements in the array. both `{1,2,3}` and `{3,2,1}` have 3 unique elements. For both your formula return `1` but the correct answer for the second one is `0`.

Comment: @Noctua: Your algo is wrong, because the numbers might not be sorted.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realized that. Allow me to fix this.

Comment: Sigh, it's so misleading the example is sorted.

Comment: NUMBERS ARE NOT SORTED , SO PLEASE .

Comment: @Noctua: In this sort of problem statement, if it is not mentioned, assume the worst case. And it is totally possible to solve this without brute force.