# Optimal way to check for number of triplets where a[k]<a[i]<a[j] for all i<j<k in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm solving a problem where I have to find number of triplets of  `Ai`, `Aj`, and `Ak` such that `Ak < Ai < Aj` and `i < j < k` in an array .

The solution to this by brute force is trivial but has complexity O(N^3). What is the optimal way to solve this?

Comment: The output size itself could be O(n^3), for a reversely sorted list (or some other permutation, just noticed the order of indices is not the same as order of elements)

Comment: for array :1 6 3 4 7 4

triplet is 1 i.e  6, 7, 4. (i=2, j=5, k=6)

Comment: Are you looking for the triplets themselves or number of triplets?

Comment: number of triplets ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [interviewstreet Triplet challenge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928575/interviewstreet-triplet-challenge)

Comment: @Peter: You've missed the the change in ordering. In the post you've linked to, fixing a choice of `j` lets you split the condition into *independent* tests on `i` and `k` which drastically simplifies the problem.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks - you are quite right I had missed that.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to solve this in O(n*log(n)) with some kind of augmented mergesort, [like with the problem of counting inversions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552591/how-to-find-the-number-of-inversions-in-an-array).

Comment: If you break the list up into three intervals, I'm pretty sure you can count in `O(n)` or maybe `O(n lg n)` time the number of triples where `i`, `j`, and `k` come from the three intervals. I haven't yet figured out how to use this in a complete algorithm that beats `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an O(n^2) approach that fixes i and iterates over the rest of the array in reverse order, keeping track of the number of elements below a[i].

```js
def count_triplets(a):
    """Count the number of triplets a[k]<a[i]<a[j] for i<j<k"""
    t = 0
    for i,ai in enumerate(a):
        kcount = 0 # The number of elements smaller than a[i]
        for x in a[:i:-1]:
            if x<ai:
                kcount += 1
            elif x>ai:
                t += kcount
    return t


A=[1,6,3,4,7,4]
print count_triplets(A)
```

### Worked example

For the given array array the interesting case is when i is equal to 1 and ai is equal to 6.

The program now works backwards over the remaining entries in the array as follows:

```
x = 4
x < ai so kcount increased to 1
x = 7
x > ai so t increased by kcount, i.e. t increased to 1
x = 4
x < ai so kcount increased to 2
x = 3
x < ai so kcount increased to 3
```

All other values of i don't end up increasing t at all, so the final value for t is 1.

### TEST CODE

The Hackerrank site wants the code to support a number of inputs.  The code below passes all tests.

```
N=input()
for n in range(N):
    A=map(int,raw_input().split())
    print count_triplets(A)
```

Comment: I think you got the order reversed. It looks like this code uses k<j. Shouldn't you count the number of j candidates, and add them to the total count whenever you find a viable k?

Comment: Do you have a test case that would give a different answer?  Note that the inner loop is working in reverse order.

Comment: The question asks for the triplets, not just the total number?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz can you please provide an example demonstrating how your algo is giving correct answer . For A=[1,6,3,4,7,4] number of triplets should me 1. I don't see how your algo will give that. I am not a python programmer so unable to figure out few lines.

Comment: @Ashish I've added an example showing how the algorithm works for this array.

Comment: @petrelharp The question body asks about triplets, but the headline says "number of triplets" (see also the clarification about that in the comments below the question).

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I have written in java what you have written in python but its giving me wrong answer in most test cases.                          `for(int i=0;i<N;++i){
            t=0;
            for(int j=N-1;j>i;j--){
                if(a[j]<a[i])
                    t+=1;
                else if(a[j]>a[i])
                    k+=t;
                    
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(""+k); `

Comment: Can you post a failing test case or a link to the problem?

Comment: This is the question https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/101hack24/challenges/twisty-tuple

Comment: I've tried my Python code and it passed all tests, so perhaps you have some problem with reading the input and converting it to integers?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I got it its because you have increased kcount at wrong place . i.e it should be if x>ai:
                kcount += 1
            elif x<ai:
                t += kcount

Comment: @Ashish I've rejected your edit because it makes the code fail the Hackerrank tests - and return the wrong answer even for the single test case in the original question.  I suspect it is a good edit for your code, but bad for the Python version for some reason.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz but in my case it passed all test cases. Its strange that language implementation is a concern here.

Comment: @Ashish I agree this is very strange, but without seeing your entire code it is hard to know what might be causing the difference.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz  can you try once to run the inner loop from i+1 to end .instead of running from reverse. I hope that is the difference .

Comment: @Ashish Yes, that works (although in the comment you had above it looked like you were running the j loop in reverse)

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz  I was trying to copy your code to java that time. later I changed as we have to keep in mind the constraint i < j < k . as a[j] > a[i]  and a[k] < a[i]. so first finding larger element and then finding smaller one and adding them does the trick . But the core remains your Algo with slight modification .